# Predict using k-fold cv model from caret package in R does not seem to work

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, predict

When I try to predict using test data on my 5 & 10 folc cv trained models the ROC I get is exactly the same for both. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong as I could not find anywhere an example for using test or new data to trained models using CV.

```
#### trainControl for both 5 and 10 fold CV
set.seed(2346)
fitControl_cv_5_roc <- trainControl(method= "cv", number = 5, 
                                    allowParallel = T, savePredictions = T, 
                                    classProbs = TRUE, 
                                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
fitControl_cv_10_roc <- trainControl(method= "cv", number = 10, allowParallel = T, 
                                     savePredictions = T, classProbs = TRUE, 
                                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#### Building models for both 5 and 10 fold CV
set.seed(2346)
model.glm.upd.cv_5_roc <- train(FO ~ Length + Code + Type + Month + Priority + Job,
                                data = Merged_train, method = "glm", 
                                trControl= fitControl_cv_5_roc, metric ="ROC")

model.glm.upd.cv_10_roc <- train(FO ~ Length + Code + Type + Month + Priority + Job, 
                                 data = Merged_train, method = "glm", 
                                 trControl= fitControl_cv_10_roc, metric ="ROC")

#### Predictions
prediction.glm.up.cv_5_roc <- predict(model.glm.upd.cv_5_roc, newdata = Merged_test)

table(prediction.glm.up.cv_5_roc, Merged_test$FO)

prediction.glm.up.cv_5_roc  one zero
                      one  7172 1963
                      zero  801 1330

roc.curve(Merged_test$FO, prediction.glm.up.cv_5_roc, plotit = T) 
Area under the curve (AUC): 0.652

prediction.glm.up.cv_10_roc <- predict(model.glm.upd.cv_10_roc, 
                                       newdata = Merged_test)

table(prediction.glm.up.cv_10_roc,Merged_test$FO)

prediction.glm.up.cv_10_roc  one zero
                       one  7172 1963
                       zero  801 1330

roc.curve(Merged_test$FO, prediction.glm.up.cv_10_roc, plotit = T) 
Area under the curve (AUC): 0.652
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (e.g. with a part of your data).

Comment: Your operation point is the same for two examples (0.5). And you are using a `seed`, in two approaches you will select the same samples.